# Do we have to pay to install custom rom?

Tags: rooting, root-access, sony-xperia

So I want to root my Android and I was wondering: Do we have to pay for installing a custom rom or is it free?

Comment: Some people will offer to do this for a charge, and some people do pay them for it since it means they don't have to do it themselves. All the information on how to do it is readily available from sites such as xda developers, so unless you really don't want to do it yourself then there's no reason to pay someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Custom ROMs are FREE. To date, I am not aware of any custom ROM that is paid (at least for the custom ROMs I have used for my Samsung Galaxy S2, S4 and Nexus 7). However, you can donate to the developers if you wish.

Rooting and installing the custom ROM yourself is free, assuming you accept all the risks, which includes bricking (or destroying) your phone.

If you are not confident enough to perform the rooting and installation of a custom ROM, you can ask an experienced person to do it for you. Of course, they may or may not request for payment.

Answer (score 0):

No custom ROM should be paid ever. Its like one of the condition of using the AOSP source code (as its open source). However a certain feature (that has been programmed by a developer completely) may be paid or may have ads. Basically my point is nobody can ask you to pay for using a custom ROM made by them. However, if you do not want the risk of flashing custom roms/rooting yourself there are people who do it for a fee. This fee is for the service they give you. You can easily flash custom ROMs at home with no difficulty with all the helps available on forums.